# Sendkeys.send not working with button click

Tags: vb.net

I tried adding and deleting letters in a textbox using `sendkeys.send` 
The `sendkeys.send` is not working on vb.net when called to a `button_click`, but if I try the same code with a `form_click` it works perfectly
The `button_click` also works when the appactivate is set to other programs such as Notepad and Ms Word but doesn't work when I try to use it on same vb.net form

```
Sendkeys.send("e")

Sendkeys.send ("{DEL} ")
```

Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it would be beneficial to post some code from your button.click event showing how you are trying to access the textbox.

Comment: You almost never need to use `SendKeys` with your own application. You can use something like `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(TextBox1.SelectionStart, "e")` instead.

Comment: How about setting a button to perform delete function in a datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `textbox` loses focus from `button`. Try *focusing* `textbox` before sending the key:

```
TextBox1.Focus()

SendKeys.Send("e")
```